# fastest implementation to cut n×n board into n connected n-minos

Tags: complexity-theory, graph-theory

I am attempting to create a puzzle to let players piece together an n×n grid using n connected n-minos (definition: connected piece of n 1×1 blocks, e.g. each of the Tetris pieces is a 4-mino). However, generating a way to cut the grid first proves to be a challenge despite seemingly easy enough for a human.

[image: example board] example board

For human, generating such a solution is a relative easy task by recursively following the following logic/pseudo-code:

**:start_of_recursion:**

- Start with a random "least connected" piece (end, corner, edge pieces that has the fewest member connecting to it) to be the starting mino block

  **:start_of_recursion:**

  - Make a "grow" in a random available direction from a random piece in the current mino

    - If "grow" results in a "separated" remaining board(, if the separated region isn't a multiple of n), try some other location and direction

      - if all location and direction has been attempted, revert to previous board configuration (shouldn't really occur?)
  - If size-n has been reached, exit recursion

  **:end_of_recursion:**
- if board has been filled, exit recursion

**:end_of_recursion:**

Performing this routine seem to generate an O(n^2) method of solution generation, however the condition checks prove to be really expensive for computers. In order to determine whether the board to be connected, a human simply checks for any "gap" inside the remaining region, and is processed in almost O(1) fashion for a simple non-overlapping graph, whereas my code implementation need to "spread" from a point on the graph into its neighboring territories and check after the spreading is complete to check whether if any points lies outside of reach (O(n) at best). Since this check is to be performed every time in the innermost iteration, it degenerates the complexity into an O(n^(3+)) problem and becomes really inefficient.

Is there a method to check for "gap" in a manner similar to that of human cognition? Or can the problem be fundamentally thought of and simplified into a problem easier for computer to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem sounds like a variant of [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). I would approach this by *constraint satisfaction* method. Below I'll use [Minizinc](http://www.minizinc.org/) pseudo-code.

A board consists of cells, each cell could be colored into one color from several. We can represent it as follows:

```
int: rows;
int: cols;
int: colors_num;

array [1...colors_num] of int: colors;
array [1..rows,1..cols] of var colors: board;
```

Next, we add constraints. For example, if a cell has color A then atleast 1 adjacent cell must have the same color A:

```
constraint forall (c in colors) (
  if board[i, j] == c then
    at_least (1, [board[i-1, j], board[i+1, j], board[i, j-1], board[i,j+1]], c)
  else
    true
  endif
```

You can describe all allowed/prohibited shapes as constraints or use some other smart approach introducing possible cuts.

Constraint satisfaction should be **much** more efficient than your recursive approach. However, it's not very scalable - if you'll try to generate a game for a gigantic board (hundreds or thousands of cells/colors), it will take quite some time and memory to generate minos.